# Can not create or build nested model in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested

I have issue when create nested model in Rails 6:

post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :post_votes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

post_vote.rb

```
class PostVote < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :posts
end
```

routes.rb

```
 resources :posts do
    resources :post_votes
  end
```

views:

```
<%= button_to post_post_votes_path(post), method: :post, remote: true, form_class: "post_vote" do%>
    <%= bootstrap_icon "arrow-up-circle", width: 20, height: 20, fill: "#333" %>
<%end%>
```

PostVost Controller

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @post_vote = PostVote.new
    if already_voted?
        # flash[:notice] = "You can't vote more than once"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        @post_vote = @post.post_votes.build(user_id: current_user.id)
    end
    # redirect_to post_path(@post)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {}
        format.js
    end
end

def already_voted?
    PostVote.where(user_id: current_user.id, post_id: params[:post_id]).exists?
end
```

I check the log file, no record was update in database
Any one known why i can not create new post_vote model?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is using belong_to without optional

```
class PostVote < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :posts
end
```

After:

```
class PostVote < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :posts, optional: true 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
@post_vote = @post.post_votes.build(user_id: current_user.id)
```

`.build` only creates the object in memory. It does not persist it to the database.

Try:

```
@post_vote = @post.post_votes.create(user_id: current_user.id)
```

or

```
@post_vote = @post.post_votes.create!(user_id: current_user.id)
```

if you want an exception to be thrown if persistence fails.

Comment: Hi @veritas1, i try to use create but the issue occur again. Do you have another solution?

Comment: @DungNguyen what is the issue? did you try `.create!` ? That will throw an exception explaining what went wrong if it does not save.

Comment: I try to use both .create and .create!. But when i check the log, no record insert in the database and no error message display.